# Unable to see the vercel deployed content in my custom domain site

Tags: next.js, vercel, godaddy-api

I have created a small project and deployed to vercel. The deployment is successful and the url generated by vercel works and shows the content without any issues. I have added a custom domain from godaddy and followed all the steps mentioned to add the domain. I also confirmed that the DNS is propagated using the DNS checker. But the link generated by vercel is working but the domain does not show the built content. is there anything I am missing? or has anyone faced similar issue and found a solution. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Its working. I had to clear the cache of my browser!!